# How to get all the page cached using Service worker

Tags: angular, ionic3, service-worker, offline-caching, offline-web-app

During initial loading of the ionic-angular4 app, how to get all pages cached using service worker.
I want to cache all the pages during the app initialization

Comment: Hey can you explain why do you think the service worker is not caching your files now? can you describe in detail what is the problem